# Android redirect all requests

Tags: android, redirect

How can I redirect all web requests from a device (or at least 1 app) from 1 address to another? For a better understanding of the situation - I explain, I bypass the blocking of the site, but since I cannot change the code of the application that sends the requests, I need to do it differently. I've already done it on PC, but I need to do it on phone too, preferably without root as it will be used by regular users as well.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's something like VPN client, Android OS support API for developing custom [VPN clients](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/vpn)

Comment: I would not call it a VPN client, since it is rather a small proxy to bypass the site blocking.

Comment: All I need is to redirect example1.com to example2.com